# Logback in a Java 9 modular application not working

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, java-9, java-module

I have a Maven project with Java 9 and am using modules. Logback seems to support this since version 1.3.0-alpha1 but unfortunately I didn't got it to work.

I get the following message from SLF4J:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
```

It looks like it can't find Logback. And inspecting the (by Jlink generated) artifact using `jimage list .../modules` I can't find anything about logback apart my logback.xml configuration file.

Maybe the problem lies in my module-info.java:

```
open module my.super.app {
    requires jackson.annotations;
    requires jdk.jsobject;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.slf4j;

    exports my.super.app;
}
```

**How and where do I declare to depend on Logback using Java 9 modules?**

Comment: Isn't this a warning and not an error?  - https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html

Comment: Yes, it's just a warning. But it indicates that it can't log/find Logback. And my log file also doesn't get written.

Comment: Well, did you add Logback to the *modulepath*?

Comment: Yes, but I guess it got removed by Jlink.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:** You declare it in your jlink-call by adding logback to the module path and using the *--bind-services* option. In your module you only define an usage of SLF4j.

**Long answer:**

I made it work in a simple example with the following parts.

Starting from version 1.8.0 [SLF4J is modularized](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#changesInVersion18) and uses the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism to find its logging backend.

Logback-classic:1.3.0-alpha4 is modularized, too, and declares a service both in *META-INF/services/org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider* and in its module descriptor:

```
provides org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider with ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider;
```

SLF4J declares in its module descriptor that it needs a SLF4JServiceProvider:

```
uses org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider
```

Therefore, in my POM (see below) I only declare a runtime dependency to Logback and my module descriptor only contains a "requires" clause to SLF4J.

My module "com.github.gv2011.j9mod.loguse" contains a main class that logs a statement to a SLF4J-Logger.

Further, it contains a logback.xml configuration file as resource. This file is accessible to Logback because it is a "miscellaneous resource", which is a resource not in a module package (see [BuiltinClassLoader](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/loader/BuiltinClassLoader.java) source).

Logback must be added explicitely to the runtime image via the jlink "*--bind-services*" option (because it is a service implementation).

Additionally, Logback and its dependencies must be available on the modulepath (jlink "*--module-path*" option).

**Module descriptor**:

```
module com.github.gv2011.j9mod.loguse {
  requires org.slf4j;
}
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.github.gv2011.j9mod</groupId>
  <artifactId>j9mod-log-use</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**logback.xml**:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <!-- "+++" just to make it obvious that this file is used: -->
      <pattern>+++ %d{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSXXX", UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.github.gv2011.j9mod.loguse.Main" level="INFO" />

  <root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

**Main-Class**:

```
package com.github.gv2011.j9mod.loguse;
import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class Main {

  private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(Main.class);

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    LOG.info("Tach.");
  }
}
```

**Output (Eclipse - Run As - Java Application)**:

```
+++ 2019-05-09T17:43:20,594Z [main] INFO  com.github.gv2011.j9mod.loguse.Main - Tach.
```

**jlink**:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jlink.exe ^
--output target\image ^
--module-path ^
target\classes;^
%M2_REPO%\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.8.0-beta4\slf4j-api-1.8.0-beta4.jar;^
%M2_REPO%\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.3.0-alpha4\logback-classic-1.3.0-alpha4.jar;^
%M2_REPO%\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.3.0-alpha4\logback-core-1.3.0-alpha4.jar ^
--bind-services ^
--launcher hello=com.github.gv2011.j9mod.loguse/com.github.gv2011.j9mod.loguse.Main ^
--add-modules com.github.gv2011.j9mod.loguse
```

**Output (target/image/bin/hello)**:

```
+++ 2019-05-10T11:45:24,844Z [main] INFO  com.github.gv2011.j9mod.loguse.Main - Tach.
```

Tested with openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64, apache-maven-3.6.0 and eclipse-jee-2019-03-R-win32-x86_64 on Windows 10, 64 Bit.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out. At the end, I just added Logback as a dependency in my module-info.java:

```
open module my.super.app {
    requires jackson.annotations;
    requires jdk.jsobject;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires ch.qos.logback.classic; //only runtime dependency

    exports my.super.app;
}
```

I guess there is no way to declare a runtime dependency (similar to Maven) - it is now also required at compile time.

Comment: I have similar problems. Which version of SLF4J were you using? 1.8.x or earlier?

Comment: In Maven I import ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.3.0-alpha4 which itself imports org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.8.0-beta1.

Comment: In newer logback versions it should be `requires logback.classic;`

Answer (score 0):

Gustave's answser is correct but it's a bit taxing to target each jar manually. Fortunately, since you're using JavaFx so probably javafx-maven-plugin as well, [you can also do](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin):

```
<runtimePathOption>MODULEPATH</runtimePathOption>
```

That way it'll place all the dependencies on the module path for you.

You'll also need

```
<bindServices>true</bindServices>
```

Full example:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>windows-build</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jlink</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <launcher>MyBeautifulApp</launcher>
                    <jlinkImageName>MyBeautifulApp</jlinkImageName>
                    <mainClass>my.beautiful.app.Main</mainClass>
                    <jlinkImageName>MyBeautifulApp</jlinkImageName>
                    <bindServices>true</bindServices>
                    <runtimePathOption>MODULEPATH</runtimePathOption>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```